# Why python dict is parsed in specific way in django template

Tags: python, django

I am creating a dict and return to django template

```
 parsing = dict()
        for idx,title in enumerate(titles):
            link = parsing.setdefault(idx, {})
            link.setdefault('title', title)
            link.setdefault('image', image)
            # print(link['image'])
        return render(request, "blog/intro.html", {'parsing':parsing})
```

But can't understand why only this code works in template. Only with 1. Why?

```
 {% for el in parsing.items %}
   {{ el.1.title }}
{% endfor%}
```

EDIT: 
let's say I need to put both title and image as elements of lists to dict. how can I also create list comprehension for images?

```
        titles = [...]
        images = [...]
        parsing = [{'title': title, 'image': image} for title in titles]
```

Comment: You can just do `link = parsing[idx] = {}` and `link['title'] = title`, you don't need to use `dict.setdefault`. What is your code supposed to be doing? It's not clear from your question what's broken.

Comment: You mean you expect to be able to do `el.title`, or…? Use `parsing.values` instead, then. Actually not sure why you’re using a dict at all; wouldn’t `parsing = [{'title': title, 'image': title} for title in titles]` be better? (With `{% for el in parsing %}` and `{{ el.title }}`.)

Comment: @Blender I use set_default because keys and structure didn't exist before the loop, and I need number of elements in dict depending on number of titles

Comment: @Ryan thanks for generator example. good example of good python

Comment: @Ryan can't understand the case if I need to iterate both values of dict/create two generators . How to do it the right way?

Comment: @Vinand: What do you mean by “iterate both values of dict”?

Comment: @Ryan I edited question. I hope my silly question is clear enough)

Comment: @Vinand: `for title, image in zip(titles, images)`?